# Hide the close icon on image

Tags: php, jquery, html, file-io

The use case is, the user can upload a new image as the profile picture. I have used the fileinput jQuery plugin for this. I am able to upload the picture and the path to the database to display it where needed.

After the image is uploaded, the user gets the option to remove the image by clicking the close icon on top right of the image.

After the user has deleted the user image the default image is displayed. What I need is the close icon should be not be displayed when the default image is being displayed (User has not uploaded any image). The close icon should be displayed only in the preview of the image while uploading and for removing an uploaded image. I hope I am not confusing. I am using the jQuery fileinput plugin for this.

Here is the code of the view file.

Input for the file input jQuery plugin.

```
<div id="kv-avatar-errors-2" class="" style="position:absolute; left:80px;   top:20px;width:800px;display:none"></div>
<div class="kv-avatar" style="width:200px">
<input id="avatar-2"  name="userprofile" type="file" class="file-loading">
</div>
```

This is the script that I have written.

```
var img = '<?php echo $user_img ?>';

    if(img)
    {
      var image = '<img src="/'+img+'" alt="Your Avatar"  style="width:100px">';
    }
    else
    {
      var image = '<img src="/uploads/profile_pics/default_avatar_male.jpg"  alt="Your Avatar" style="width:100px">';

    }
    <?php if(isset($editMode) && !empty($editMode)) {?>

      fileInput(image);

    <?php } ?>
        $('.close').click(function() {

                  var userId = '<?php echo $user_id ?>';
                  var image_path = '<?php echo $user_img ?>';

                  jQuery.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "<?php echo site_url('Users/deleteProfileImage')  ?>",
                      data: {user_id: userId, dp: image_path},
                      dataType: 'json',
                      success: function(response) {
                      var image = '<img  src="/uploads/profile_pics/default_avatar_male.jpg" alt="Your Avatar"  style="width:100px">';
                      $(".file-default-preview").html(image);
                      document.querySelector(".close").style.display="none";

                  }
              });
          });
        });

function fileInput(image){

$("#avatar-2").fileinput({
        overwriteInitial: true,
        maxFileSize: 1500,
        showClose: true,
        showZoom: false,
        showCaption: false,
        showBrowse: false,
        browseOnZoneClick: true,
        removeLabel: '',
        removeIcon: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>',
        removeTitle: 'Cancel or reset changes',
        elErrorContainer: '#kv-avatar-errors-2',
        msgErrorClass: 'alert alert-block alert-danger',
        defaultPreviewContent: image + '<h6 class="text-muted">Click to  select</h6>',
        layoutTemplates: {main2: '{preview} {browse}'},
        allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "png", "gif"]
    });

}
```

The class of the close icon is .close.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like something is wrong with:

```
document.querySelector(".close").style.display="none".
```

You could try

```
$('.close').hide();
```

instead.